# Pyinstaller -bash Permission denied

Tags: pyinstaller

I generate a standalone file from a project using `pyinstaller -F lpxl_handler_simp.py`. It generates the file and executes well in the dist/ directory till I get the file to another directory. The moment I drop it in another directory and try to execute it through the Linux terminal, I get the `-bash: ./lpxl_handler_simp: Permission deined` error message.
I tried the `pyinstaller -D lpxl_handler_simp.py` option as well it gives the same error. Here is my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['lpxl_handler_simp.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='lpxl_handler_simp',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Any suggestion to help this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to give it the permission using the command `chmod`.
If it's not working try to use `chmod` while being in super use `sudo su`.